# How to monkeypatch buildin OPEN functions

Tags: python, pytest

I need to write a test for a function that writes into a file as follows:

```
with open(name=ccf.status_dir_path + '/' + script_normalized, mode='w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Of course I would like to avoid the file to be created, so I need to monkeypatch "open", but since "open" doesn't belong to any class or module I do not know what to give as first parameter to

```
monkeypatch.setattr(??, "open", patched_open)
```

Comment: `unittest.mock` has something specifically for this...

Comment: But we moved away from unittest. Anything similar for pytest?

Comment: You can just use the mock part, it's separate to `TestCase` etc. and works perfectly well with pytest.

Comment: @jonrshape: Would be brilliant to point out to which question my question should be a duplicate! I didn't find any duplicate during a 30 minute search. So it is difficult to explain the difference to something unknown.

Comment: ...it's literally listed at the top of the question. Also I've told you where to find it, so you could just look in the docs.

Comment: @jonrshape:
1. Thanx, I have no idea how you found that since there is only the word "open" in common, +1
2. I just saw your comment and didn't look at the top of the page, because I didn't expect another related information at a different place. Sry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122993/discussion-between-mstuebner-and-jonrsharpe).